# Using Asio4All on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, asio

I installed Asio4all, which solved an issue I was having in Windows 10 with regard to a delay from my midi keyboard. It solves the problem fine, but now when I try to watch a video in Chrome or something it doesn't work unless I switch ableton back to MME / Direct X.

I guess I need to make a change in the windows control panel somewhere to make Asio4All default, does anyone know where to do this on Windows 10?

Comment: Are you talking about audio output devices?

Comment: I'm talking about getting sound out of my speakers from my laptop

Comment: Right click on the speaker icon on your taskbar and select Playback decides. You can set the default output device there.